# angular scope of ng-model to filter model of a different scope

Tags: angularjs

Reading the [docs tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03), under Template. The code below is taken from app/index.html

Does angular allows cross visibility of sibling  scopes?

How is it that the data named query which is is in scope 1 is available to the filter in scope 2 which is a sibling and not a parent scope? Thanks.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"> //-----------scope 1 -----------------
      <!--Sidebar content-->

      Search: <input ng-model="query">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">  //-----------scope 2 -----------------
      <!--Body content-->

      <ul class="phones">
        <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query">
          {{phone.name}}
          <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a $scope tree, starting from $rootScope. In your HTML, there is only 1 scope in play (ignoring ngRepeat, which creates its own child scope with each iteration).  So when a user enters a value in the input box, it is being bound to query which resides in the same scope as the sibling div.  Hence why both query is bound to the same scope variable, even though they are within sibling divs.

One way to break the binding is to introduce a child scope for your input control. For example, ngController will create a child scope that inherits from the parent scope. As soon as a key is pressed, it creates a copy of `query` in the child scope. This breaks two-way binding because now two copies of the query variable exist on different scopes.

```
<div class="col-md-2" ng-controller="anyCtrl"> //-----------scope 1 -----------------
  <!--Sidebar content-->

  Search: <input ng-model="query">

</div>
```

You should visualize your $scope tree and get to know which directives will create child scopes.  Also keep in mind that $scope variable lookups (reads) are resolved through prototypical $scope inheritance (meaning the definition of the $scope variable could exist higher up the $scope tree). But $scope variable writes will write to its immediate scope - sometimes breaking the apparent binding as I've explained above.